# convert php array of multidimensional arrays to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

Hi i have that php code example :

```
$array1 = array("fruits" => "banana","vegetables" => "tomatos");
$array2 = array("name" => "Jack","Age" => "32");

$array3 = array($array1, $array2);

echo json_encode($array3);
```

javascript code includes jquery :

```
   var json_data = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'scripts/myfile.php',
                data: { action: 'myaction' },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
```

how to convert json_data to an array and affect the two of $array1 & $array2 to javascript arrays !

this is the json_data content :

```
"{"HUM":[{"label":"2014-10-16 17:08:55","y":"58"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:55","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:50","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:45","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:40","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:35","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:30","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:25","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:20","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:15","y":"56"},

"TEMP":[{"label":"2014-10-16 17:08:55","y":"26"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:55","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:50","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:45","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:40","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:35","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:30","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:25","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:20","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:15","y":"24"},

"HUM2":[{"label":"2014-10-16 17:08:55","y":"38"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:55","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:50","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:45","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:40","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:35","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:30","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:25","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:20","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:15","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:10","y":"36"},

"TEMP2":[{"label":"2014-10-16 17:08:55","y":"23"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:55","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:50","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:45","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:40","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:35","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:30","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:25","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:20","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:15","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:10","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:05","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:00","y":"24"}]}"
```

now i want to convert it to array and then serparate arrays HUM - TEMP - HUM2 - TEMP2

Comment: `obj = JSON.parse(result);`

Comment: `obj = $.parseJSON(result);`

Comment: it gives that error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: `json_data` in your example is a jqXHR object. You need to access the data in the success callback: `success: function(result) {alert(result[1].name);//alerts Jack},`

Comment: You should remove the "," after the success function.

Do I understand you right, you want to get one array back that is a merge of <?php $array1 and $array2 ?> that would be with <?php $array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2); ?>

Comment: ok can i do json_encode($array1, $array2); ?

Comment: i did console.log and it returns data from db like this 0: Objectlabel: "2014-10-16 17:08:55"y: "58"__proto__: Object1: Objectlabel: "2014-10-15 08:16:55"y: "56"__proto__: Object2: Objectlabel: "2014-10-15 08:16:50"y: "56"__proto__: Object3: Objectlabel: "2014-10-15 08:16:45"y: "56"__proto__: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11: Object12: Object13: Object

Comment: what output format do you want? What you are dping in php doesn't appear to be very useful in JS

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
$array3 = array(array1, array2);
```

here array1 and array2 considered as string without quotes, so you will not get your answer. This should be `PHP` variable. You have to include `$` sign in this.

```
$array3 = array($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery $.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation on `dataType` when it is set to `json`.

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

The object result is already a JSON object in the success function.  So you can simply use `result[0]['fruits']` or `result[1]['name']` to access the relevant arrays.

*Edit* : Corrected index as @charlietfl pointed out.

Comment: incorrect regarding `result['fruits']` , the way OP is merging arrays of arrays ....would be `result[0]['fruits']` or `result[1]['name']`

Answer (score 0):

`$array3 = array(array1, array2);` should be `$array3 = array($array1, $array2);`